# What does "unnatural" mean?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-language

If humans are part of nature; everything that we do is natural. Why is a bird's nest considered natural while a human's building is considered unnatural? Don't human-made materials come from nature? How is "natural" defined that it excludes human-made materials such as money, buildings, phones, etc?

Comment: Perhaps you are confusing something being MADE vs CREATED also. Birds can do things without using synthetic parts. Man for the most part uses synthetic parts if he were to build a nest so that the nest would last longer. Natural also has a context of normal circumstances. Without synthetic materials how advanced would human kind be a part from beast of the field? So something is unnatural someone cheats or takes advantage of something that does not have the same availability. Naturally a gorilla is stronger than a man, but a man can build a machine stronger than the gorilla.It's Advantage.

Comment: Pease do more research on a question before asking it here.  There is actually a concurrent and better researched question which has been asked on this board today:  https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/90591/what-is-the-meaning-of-natural

Comment: "better researched" i don't know. Both questions seem similarly superficial trying to philosophize where there is no actual issue.

Comment: @tkruse You don't seem to understand the philosophical issue. Which is okay. You have to admit though that that other question is better researched... ;)

Comment: @tkruse "Both questions seem similarly superficial trying to philosophize" What's superficial? Unnatural?

Comment: @Logikal "Natural also has a context of normal circumstances. Without synthetic materials how advanced would human kind be a part from beast of the field? " Very advanced. Look at which state the natural field is brought...

Comment: Why can't you find the answer in a dictionary?

Comment: When it's exactly 12 minutes 15 seconds past noon in Paris, 4039 AD, we will know the answer ... to this all-important question.